# Выделение вокруг элемента

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#

Столкнулся со странной проблемой. Не могу убрать пунктирную линию вокруг элементов, те имеется кнопка, которую я стилизировал (или любой другой контрол), после клика по ней вокруг появляется пунктирная линия, которую никак не убрать.

```
<Button IsTabStop="False"  Style="{StaticResource NoneStyleButton}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                <Path 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Margin="1,1,1,1"
        Fill="#444"
        Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"/>
 </Button>

 <Style x:Key="NoneStyleButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
                    <Label Name="NoneStyleButtonItemPresenter" >
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Label>                        
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding IsEneble}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="NoneStyleButtonItemPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value="0.2" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding IsEnable}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="NoneStyleButtonItemPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Привет.

Приведите пример кода кнопки и стилей к ней. Может попробовать просто навесить border: 0 на img и a, a:focus, a:visited, a:hover и посмотреть, когда она исчезнет.

Comment: Этот эффект проявляется не только после стилизации элементов, к примеру, стандартный Slider, получает такую же пунктирную рамку вокруг.

Comment: Установите у всех элементов, на которых Вы не хотите видеть рамку, свойство: Focusable=false;